# pivot_longer() for multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyr

```
df <- data.frame(year = c("2001", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2002", 
                          "2003", "2003", "2003", "2004", "2004", "2004"), 
             city = c("Rome", "Rome", "Rome", "London", "London", "London", 
                      "New York", "New York", "New York", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris"),
             position_1 = c("first", "first", "first", "second", "second", "second", 
                            "third", "third", "third", "fourth", "fourth", "fourth"),
             position_2 = c("fifth", "fifth", "fifth", "sixth", "sixth", "sixth", 
                            "seventh", "seventh", "seventh", "eighth", "eighth", "eighth"), 
             position_3 = c("ninth", "ninth", "ninth", "eleventh", "eleventh", "eleventh", 
                            "twelfth", "twelfth", "twelfth", "thirteenth", "thirteenth", "thirteenth"))
```

I need a table as follows:

[image]

I have tried the following command, but it didn't work.

```
df <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = position_1:position_3,
               names_to = "new_position")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need the following ?

```r
library(tidyr)
df |>
  pivot_longer(
    cols = position_1:position_3,
    values_to = "new_position",
    names_to = NULL
  )
#> # A tibble: 36 × 3
#>    year  city   new_position
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>       
#>  1 2001  Rome   first       
#>  2 2001  Rome   fifth       
#>  3 2001  Rome   ninth       
#>  4 2001  Rome   first       
#>  5 2001  Rome   fifth       
#>  6 2001  Rome   ninth       
#>  7 2001  Rome   first       
#>  8 2001  Rome   fifth       
#>  9 2001  Rome   ninth       
#> 10 2002  London second      
#> # ℹ 26 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

A shortcut for `pivot_longer()` is naming the columns you don't want pivoted with minus signs:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(-year, -city)) %>% 
  select(-name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way of doing it:

Steps:

1. Make the data long.
2. Change the positions to numbers (if you wanted to sort by position, it would give you it in alphabetical order - it's better to convert it to a factor, and best to convert it to a number! :-)
3. Sort by the column 'name', as in the desired output
4. Remove the 'name' column
5. Remove duplicate rows

```
library(dplyr)

nums <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelfth", "thirteenth")

df |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("position"), values_to = "new_position") |>
  mutate(new_position = factor(new_position, levels = nums) |> as.integer()) |> 
  arrange(name) |> 
  select(-name) |> 
  distinct()
```

Output:

```
   year  city     new_position
   <chr> <chr>           <int>
 1 2001  Rome                1
 2 2002  London              2
 3 2003  New York            3
 4 2004  Paris               4
 5 2001  Rome                5
 6 2002  London              6
 7 2003  New York            7
 8 2004  Paris               8
 9 2001  Rome                9
10 2002  London             11
11 2003  New York           12
12 2004  Paris              13
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides `pivot_longer`, you can try a base R option as well

```
> cbind(df[1:2], new_position = stack(df[-(1:2)])[[1]])
   year     city new_position
1  2001     Rome        first
2  2001     Rome        first
3  2001     Rome        first
4  2002   London       second
5  2002   London       second
6  2002   London       second
7  2003 New York        third
8  2003 New York        third
9  2003 New York        third
10 2004    Paris       fourth
11 2004    Paris       fourth
12 2004    Paris       fourth
13 2001     Rome        fifth
14 2001     Rome        fifth
15 2001     Rome        fifth
16 2002   London        sixth
17 2002   London        sixth
18 2002   London        sixth
19 2003 New York      seventh
20 2003 New York      seventh
21 2003 New York      seventh
22 2004    Paris       eighth
23 2004    Paris       eighth
24 2004    Paris       eighth
25 2001     Rome        ninth
26 2001     Rome        ninth
27 2001     Rome        ninth
28 2002   London     eleventh
29 2002   London     eleventh
30 2002   London     eleventh
31 2003 New York      twelfth
32 2003 New York      twelfth
33 2003 New York      twelfth
34 2004    Paris   thirteenth
35 2004    Paris   thirteenth
36 2004    Paris   thirteenth
```

or

```
> cbind(df[1:2], new_position = unname(unlist(df[-(1:2)])))
   year     city new_position
1  2001     Rome        first
2  2001     Rome        first
3  2001     Rome        first
4  2002   London       second
5  2002   London       second
6  2002   London       second
7  2003 New York        third
8  2003 New York        third
9  2003 New York        third
10 2004    Paris       fourth
11 2004    Paris       fourth
12 2004    Paris       fourth
13 2001     Rome        fifth
14 2001     Rome        fifth
15 2001     Rome        fifth
16 2002   London        sixth
17 2002   London        sixth
18 2002   London        sixth
19 2003 New York      seventh
20 2003 New York      seventh
21 2003 New York      seventh
22 2004    Paris       eighth
23 2004    Paris       eighth
24 2004    Paris       eighth
25 2001     Rome        ninth
26 2001     Rome        ninth
27 2001     Rome        ninth
28 2002   London     eleventh
29 2002   London     eleventh
30 2002   London     eleventh
31 2003 New York      twelfth
32 2003 New York      twelfth
33 2003 New York      twelfth
34 2004    Paris   thirteenth
35 2004    Paris   thirteenth
36 2004    Paris   thirteenth
```